# Упаковка стандартных байтов(8 бит) в 6 бит

Tags: java, алгоритм, битовые-операции

На вход поступает какой-то файл (не важно какой). Мне необходимо упаковать 
8-битные байты в 6-битные. Т.е. поступило 3 8-битных байта (`10101000 00001111 01011010`), преобразуем их в следующее: `101010 000000 111101 011010`.

Я пробовал сделать это с помощью строк (представление числа в виде строки 0 и 1, а потом нарезка этих строк), но данный подход не эффективен. Остаются побитовые операции. Но в этом случае я не разобрался с тем, как нарезать байты. (каждый раз маска меняется: для первого раза, чтобы отсечь 6 старших бит нужна такая (`11111100`), два младших бита перекочевывают в другой байт, и становятся в нем старшими, для второго раза нам нужно отсечь уже 4 старших бита, ведь 2 уже пришли из другого байта, и маска становится такой (`11110000`).

Мне не нужен код, я хочу лишь алгоритм.

Comment: На самом деле, в нескольких масках ничего страшного нет

Comment: Всё совсем просто - запишите все биты в единый массив, потом прочитайте массив и поставьте разделители.

Comment: Кстати, что у вас будет разделителем? Пробел?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin массив какого типа, как вы запишете в него биты, чем являются разделители, как вы их поставите и как получите итоговые "байты"? Не похоже на "совсем просто"

Comment: Я думал, что изложение всей задачи окажется излишним, поэтому указал лишь часть, но как оказалось, что это нужно сделать. Так вот: существует некий буфер(одномерный массив) с уже установленным размером (пускай 5*5); мне необходимо последовательно заполнять этот буфер байтами из файла, затем производить с ним определенную манипуляцию, а затем преобразованный буфер писать в другой файл, и так по циклу, пока не прочтем входной файл. Соль в том, что размер байта у этого буфера должен быть 6 бит; с этого момента и начинается вышеописанная подзадача.

Comment: @Nabla строго говоря, в любом байте 8 бит. В вашем случае же 2 бита в байте (видимо, первые) будут незначащие

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой код в меня получился на C#. Алгоритм вы поймете, я добавил комментарии.

```
byte[] array = new byte[]
{
    Convert.ToByte("10101000", 2),
    Convert.ToByte("00001111", 2),
    Convert.ToByte("01011010", 2),
};
int cut = 6; // на сколько бит резать

List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
int remainder = 0; // остаток
int remBits = 0;   // сколько бит в остатке
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    remainder = (remainder << 8) | array[i]; // добавляем в остаток следующий байт
    remBits += 8; // количество бит в остатке увеличиваем на длину байта
    while (remBits >= cut) // пока в остатке остается кусок, который мы может вырезать
    {
        result.Add((byte)(remainder >> (remBits - cut))); // берем старшие cut бит
        remainder &= (1 << (remBits - cut)) - 1; // обнуляем их

        remBits -= cut; // вычитаем биты из остатка
    }
}

if (remBits > 0) // если что то осталось (например, если нельзя нацело разделить), добавляем то, что осталось
    result.Add((byte)(remainder << (cut - remBits)));
```

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, зачем нужен последний if, где добавляем какой-то остаток, если есть сдвиг этого остатка к старшим разрядам на следующем шаге (remainder = (remainder << 8) | array[i];). Потом-то мы все-равно отделяем от получившегося столько, сколько нужно(в цикле)?

Comment: @Nabla Допустим вы режете по 6 бит. И подали в на вход всего один байт. Внутри цикла `for` вы отрезали первые 6 бит. А осталось еще 2. Эти 2 оставшиеся биты и закидываются в последнем `if`.

Comment: Я про то, что не выполняет ли это же действие (remainder = (remainder << 8) | array[i];) в купе с циклом?

Comment: @Nabla Вы про то, что в последнем `if ` ошибка? Да, возможно там нужен сдвиг остатка влево.

Comment: @Nabla я исправил ошибку в конце. `remainder = (remainder << 8) | array[i];` в моем примере с 1 байтом на входе, эта строчка всего один раз выполняется. И в остатке на позиции 2 младших бит остаются 2 младших бита с первого байта. И их нужно переместить в старшие биты в последнем `if`

Comment: Не подскажите, как мне обратно из 6-битных байтов 8-битные получить? На вашем примере я упаковал в 6 бит, затем создал цикл (в другом методе), который в последствии преобразует 6-бтиные байты в 8-битные, только пока не клеиться.

Comment: Пока не нашел нормального способа вставить сюда свой код(

Comment: @Nabla там все должно быть просто, в 2 местах заменить `8` на `6`. В комменты плохо вставлять код

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема в том, что ваш метод просто распихивает обрезки друг за другом, а информации по тому, как формировать старые(те, что были до разбиения, к примеру) числа просто нет. Непонятно как из этих разрозненных ячеек собирать новые (8-битные) байты.